# Export .CSV file with changes made to same name and folder as import

Tags: powershell, csv

I need to change some date formats in incoming .csv files so they can be properly processed later on.

I am able to change the date formats but I can't figure out how to export my .csv so it keeps the same name and remains in the same folder. Multiple .csv files will pop up in the folder from time to time these have to be processed one by one.

One CSV file works fine, exporting to another folder also but then he writes everything into the same csv.

This is what I've got:

`Import-Csv -Path (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test2\input '*.csv').FullName | ForEach-Object { $_.SamplingDateTime = '{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}' -f $(Get-Date $_.SamplingDateTime);  $_.DateOfBirth = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $(Get-Date $_.DateOfBirth) $_ } | export-csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Test2\input\*.csv`

export-csv : Cannot perform operation because the path resolved to more than one file. This command cannot operate on multiple files. --> makes sense but don't know how else to do it, quite new to the whole thing. ..

Maybe trough a quick detour into a subfolder? It must be done trough powershell.

Some advice?

Comment: does the `-append` flag do just that, and only append to the file without replacing the changes you've made?

Comment: Instead of putting the `Get-ChildItem` inside the `-Path` of `Import-Csv` you could use it in a `Foreach ( $csv in (Get-ChildItem...) ){}` This way you have access to the parameters `$csv.FullName ; $csv.Name ; $csv.DirectoryName` and others you might need for each single csv. So they can be used in your `Export-Csv`

Comment: I believe that ```export-csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Test2\input\*.csv``` should be a single discrete file, not a wildcard value. e.g. ```export-csv -NoTypeInformation C:\Test2\input\result.csv```.

Comment: Yes, '-append' adds the lines to the csv but without replacing and get stuck in a loop  ( keeps adding the lines)

Answer (score 1):

You do not have access to the filepath in the pipeline using import-csv first.  The path of the output file needs to be tracked somehow to be used in the final export-csv command.  Try something like this

```
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Test2\input '*.csv' | ForEach-Object {
        $path = $_.FullName;
        $_.FullName | Import-Csv | ForEach-Object { 
            $_.SamplingDateTime = '{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}' -f $(Get-Date $_.SamplingDateTime);  
            $_.DateOfBirth = '{0:yyyyMMdd}' -f $(Get-Date $_.DateOfBirth);
            $_ 
        } | export-csv -NoTypeInformation -Path $path     
    }
```

Comment: File gets adjusted but is empty afterwards; Import-Csv : You must specify either the -Path or -LiteralPath parameters, but not both.
At line:3 char:10
+     $_ | Import-Csv | ForEach-Object {

Comment: I believe we were missing a semicolon and/or line break between the DateOfBirth line and the next.  Have another go at it

Comment: Sorry, one other change before Import-Csv.  Change $_ to $_.FullName

Comment: indeed found it! It works. Thanks! (I put a ; before the last $_.